# Generate element java class using JAXB from XSD

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I had an xsd document, and I want to generate java class from it using JAXB.
Before, there was one element like this:

```
<element name="myResponse" type="param:response>
<complexType name="response">
    <sequence>
        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="reference" type="param:myType" />
        ...
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

and myType is defined as a complexType, too.
Then I get the generated class MyResponse.java and Reference.java.
I can assign the value of "reference" by:

```
ArrayList<myType> l = new new ArrayList<myType>()
response.getReference().addAll(l);
```

and it worked.

Now I just removed the maxOccurs="unbounded", it does not work anymore.
response is no longer of type List, but JAXBElement.
I tried to use:

```
myType t = new myType();
response.getReference().setValue(t);
```

and

```
myType t = new myType();
response.setReference(t);
```

but neither works.

Can somebody tells me what is the right way to do when it's not a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not enough reputation so far so I cannot comment questions, hence I'll take a responsibility to guess what your problem is (there is not enough information about how you manage to get your "response" variable in java code). I believe this should have nothing to do with either your type acceptes a sequence of elements or only a single one.

1. If you generate Java classes from your schema using xjc tool you should finally have `ObjectFactory.class` generated along with other classes representing your types. Examine that one to understand how your objects are created.
2. Since your response element is the top level one in your schema it is annotated with `@XmlElementDecl` [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementDecl.html) and have the type JAXBElement
3. You "response" has never been of a type List (check the generated class). It only had a "reference" field of a `List<MyType>` type

So if you unmarshall data from xml file you should do it in the following way

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Response response = ((JAXBElement<Response>) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File("YOUR_FILE_PATH"))).getValue();
MyType t = new ObjectFactory().createMyType();
response.setReference(t);
```

This basically would be a proper way (including creating your new objects using `ObjectFactory.class` methods).